# Is there a helper method for parameterizing input for sql queries?

Tags: c#, sql, ado.net

First off, I'm aware that parameterization can be done in ADO. My question is whether there is a general method available for being able to do this parameterization without having to have the `SqlCommand` available. The short reason for this is that the query is built separately from the items that might be parameterized, so I'm wondering if there is a way to safe-parameterize without having to do some very difficult work synchronizing the two processes.

Comment: You can use a [`SqlParameterCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.aspx). When you are going to use the `SqlCommand` you can add these parameters.

Comment: If using parameterization, is it possible to see the rendered SqlCommand (where the parameters have been replaced by their actual values)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [SQLParameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.aspx) class:

```
public void AddSqlParameters() 
{
// ... 
// create categoriesDataSet and categoriesAdapter 
// ...

  categoriesAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(
    "@CategoryName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 80).Value = "toasters";
  categoriesAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(
    "@SerialNum", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 239;
  categoriesAdapter.Fill(categoriesDataSet);

}
```